# Why Debian requires manual edit of /etc/apt/source.list to receive LTS updates?

Tags: debian, apt, lts

Why in Debian, you must manually edit your `/etc/apt/source.list` in order to receive LTS updates as explained in the [official Debian LTS Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using)?

Why it's not like Ubuntu where LTS updates arrive without the need of this manual change on `/etc/apt/source.list`?

this is the an original `/etc/apt/source.list` after the install

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

and this is the one from [official Debian LTS Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using)

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Where does it say you have to make a manual edit? It even says "Note that if you already follow security.debian.org (and you should), this should mostly be a noop"

Comment: @muru I have updated my question showing differences from post install `source.list` and LTS required one. My english level it's not enough to understand the "noop" phrase from the wiki. I also remember from previous Debian releases that this manual edit of `source.list` was required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian LTS doesn’t require editing `sources.list`. The differences in your examples are the added `contrib` and `non-free` sections, which are only needed if you require packages from those sections; in such cases, `sources.list` would already contain the relevant entries. They are not enabled by default, which is why your post-installation `sources.list` file doesn’t contain them.